# How do I compare two 3D Plots in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, compare

I want to compare two Matplotlib 3D Plots in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ["orange", "blue", "black", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "gold"]

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
z2 = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.gca(projection="3d")

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.gca(projection="3d")

fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig3.gca(projection="3d")

for i in range(0, 8):
    ax1.plot([x[i], x[i+1]], [y[i], y[i+1]], [z[i], z[i+1]], color=colors[i])
    ax2.plot([x[i], x[i+1]], [y[i], y[i+1]], [z[i], z[i+1]], color=colors[i])
    ax3.plot([x[i], x[i+1]], [y[i], y[i+1]], [z2[i], z2[i+1]], color=colors[i])

fig1.show()
fig2.show()
fig3.show()

print(fig1 == fig2, fig1 == fig3, fig2 == fig3)
print(ax1 == ax2, ax1 == ax3, ax2 == ax3) # Tried with "ax" just to see if it would work.
```

My code shows three figures:

- Figure 1 (left)
- Figure 2 (top right)
- Figure 3 (bottom right)

[image: Figures]

The output of:

```
print(fig1 == fig2, fig1 == fig3, fig2 == fig3)
print(ax1 == ax2, ax1 == ax3, ax2 == ax3) # Tried with "ax" just to see if it would work.
```

Is:

```
False False False
False False False
```

But Figure 1 and Figure 2 are equal. Only Figure 3 is different. I was expecting an output of:

```
True, False, False
True, False, False
```

Help?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to compare  `figure` objects. Also, to me Figures 1 and 2 are not equal because Figure 1 is larger than Figure 2 and has more axis ticks and grid lines.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to compare the underlying *data* of the plots, instead of their graphical outputs? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 1 - Figure 1 and Figure 2 are equal. Matplotlib just shrinks the axes and grid lines to accommodate window size.
2 - Yes, I could compare the underlying data, but I'd prefer to compare the actual plots.

Comment: when you run plt.figure() or fig.gca, new objects are formed having separate id values which are not equal. try print(fig1, fig2, fig3) to see objects at different addresses.

Comment: @Vedant36 thanks! Do these objects have any parameter that I can use for the intended comparison? I'm looking it up, but I'm also open to your suggestions.